# Cannot fail jenkins shell script on dotnet build fail

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have shell script to build dotnet solution I run it in Jenkins but it reports the build was successful even if dotnet build return error.

My build code:

```
if [ -f $SOLUTION ]; then
  echo "Building ${branch} :" | tee msbuild.log
  STATUS=$(dotnet build $SOLUTION -v m -o $BUILD_TARGET/${branch}) | tee msbuild.log
  if ! [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "MSBuild failed"
     exit 1;
  fi
```

else
echo "Cannot find solution: ${SOLUTION}!" | tee msbuild.log
fi
I'm checking last status code to detect error and then fail Jenkins job by returning 1, but for some reasons it doesn't even execute the if block.
In Jenkins console I can see the error message from dotnet build:
[image]
What can cause this behavior? Can it be due this setting: `#!/bin/bash +x`

EDIT: Fixed the error above with current version of the code above. Now every build fails due to syntax error: `[: -eq: unary operator expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$STATUS` variable is not set. I think the `tee` pipe is not returning a value.

You could try

```
if [ -f $SOLUTION ]; then
  echo "Building ${branch} :" | tee msbuild.log
  STATUS=$(dotnet build $SOLUTION -v m -o $BUILD_TARGET/${branch})
  echo "$STATUS" > msbuild.log
  if ! [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "MSBuild failed"
     exit 1;
  fi
```